# How to set "NULL (empty)" to 0 within a function R

Tags: r

I've been writing a function to do with sales and sometimes there's no sales for that method so R returns null(empty) how can I set this to zero? Because I will be using that value in a list and then in a matrix with other lists if the list isn't long enough it starts the list again and it messes up my dashboard. Example:

```
s1<- c("sales_method1", "sales_method3")
s2<- c(50, 100)
df<-data.frame(s1, s2)

my_function <- function(df){

breakdown_of_sales <- lapply(split(df$s2, df$s1), sum)

sales_method1 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method1
sales_method2 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method2
sales_method3 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method3

list <- c(sales_method1, sales_method2, sales_method3)

Pot  <<- matrix(`list`,
               nrow = 1,
               ncol = 3)
}
```

This returns 50, 100, 50  as

```
sales_method2 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method2
```

returns null, making my pot contain 50,100,50 when I want it to default to equal 0 when it is null, making it 50,0,100

Comment: add `return(0)` at the good place in your code

Comment: after your `list <- ` call, use `if (is.null(list)) list <- 0`

Comment: @JRR Where would that be? I don't understand the documentation. I tried adding it just after     sales_method2 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method2 but that didn't didn't change the output, i also tried     return((method2 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method2) , 0) but that threw an error

Comment: @Benjamin `list <-  c(sales_method1, sales_method2, sales_method3)
if (is.null(list)) {list <- 0}`  would it be like this? I'm fairly new to programming and I'm struggling to get my head around if statements

Comment: `list <- c(sales_method1, sales_method2, sales_method3)` do you mean a vector or a list. if you want a list then write `my_list <- list(sales_method1, sales_method2, sales_method3)`. `list` is a name of R function so it is good to not use it as your variable name. by the way, yes you did it correctly.

Comment: @Alice,  this is not what I'm actually writing, this is just the small scale reproducible example. When I added the if statement into my code as described above it still had the same end result of the 50,100,50 matrix

Comment: you do not define `sales_method2` so why do you need it.

Comment: I've sorted it now in this example and in my actual code. Thank you @Benjamin. @Alice I know there is no data for `sales_method2` , that is what the whole problem is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want or not. However, I tried it and worked.

```
s1<- c("sales_method1", "sales_method3")
s2<- c(50, 100)
df<-data.frame(s1, s2)

my_function <- function(df){

    breakdown_of_sales <- lapply(split(df$s2, df$s1), sum)

    sales_method1 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method1
    sales_method2 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method2
    sales_method3 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method3
    sales_method <- list(sales_method1, sales_method2, sales_method3)
    for(i in 1:length(sales_method)){
        if (any(is.null(sales_method[[i]]))){
            sales_method[[i]] <- 0
        }
    }


    list <- sales_method



    Pot  <<- matrix(`list`,
                    nrow = 1,
                    ncol = 3)
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I want, I ended up using `sales_method2 <- breakdown_of_sales$sales_method2 if (is.null(sales_method2)) {sales_method2 <- 0} . I don't fully understand for loops yet, and also in my program there's 20+ methods and I've only seen 2 ever get null

Comment: `for` loop is good to loop over many list or vectors elements. it is good to use a method to make it is easy for you than just repeat your code.

Comment: I'll add it on to the list of things to learn, thanks. I've also ticked and updooted you :)